# How to make typescript take filtering on data type into account

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have these interfaces:

```js
interface ParsedUrlQuery {
  [key: string]: string | string[]
}

interface URLParams {
  [key: string]: string
}
```

I then write the function:

```js
const getParamsFromQuery = (query: ParsedUrlQuery): URLParams => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(query).filter(([_key, value]) => typeof value === 'string')
  )
}
```

I get a typescript error:

```
Type '{ [k: string]: string | string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'URLParams'.
  'string' index signatures are incompatible.
    Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

Why does this not work and what do I need to make typescript take into account this filter action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a [typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) which lets you tell typescript that if your function returns true - then `value is string`.

```
const getParamsFromQuery = (query: ParsedUrlQuery): URLParams => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(query).filter((kv): kv is [string, string] => typeof kv[1] === 'string')
  )
}
```

Comment: It seems to be what I need, but I still get the error unfortunately

Comment: edited. I'm not certain why - but typescript does not seem to like binding a type predicate with something you destructured.